# Symmetric and antisymmetric matrices as subspaces of $M_{3 \times 3}(\Bbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that the set $S$ compound of $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrices and the set $A$ of the antisymmetric matrices, are subspaces of $M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb R)$. Determine basis for $S$ and $A$. Show, using a $\dim$ relation, that $S \oplus A = M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb R)$.

My solution:

Set $S$ can be described as any matrix in the follow pattern:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & d & e \\
d & b & f \\
e & f & c
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Set $A$ follows this other pattern:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & d & e \\
-d & 0 & f \\
-e & -f & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Proof for both sets being subspaces of $M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb R)$:

To summarize this post I'll affirm that set $S$ and $A$ are closed under multiplication, addition, and contains the $ \left\{ 0 \right\} $, which make them subspaces. It's easy to see that.

Vector space $M_{3 \times 3}(\Bbb R)$ follows this pattern:
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
To see that the set $S$ is included there, take $b=d, c=g, h=f$.
To see that the set $A$ is included there, take $d=-b, h=-c, f=-h$ and $a=e=i=0$
Hence, because of that and the affirmation made previously, we can assume that $S$ and $A$ are subspaces of $M_{3 \times 3}(\Bbb R)$

Basis:

For $S$:
$$
B_{s}= \left\{
 \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
, \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
,  \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
,  \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
,  \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} ,
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
\right\} \\
\dim(S) = 6
$$

For $A$:
$$
B_{a}= \left\{
 \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
, \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
,  \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
\right\}\\
\dim(A) = 3
$$

Proof for $S \oplus A = M_{3x3}(R)$ using a dimension relation:

Using that $\dim$ relation:
$$
\dim(a+b) = \dim(a) + \dim(b) - \dim(a \cap b)
$$ We can assume that:
$$
\dim(S) + \dim(A) = 9
$$ Since $\dim(M_{3 \times 3}(\Bbb R)) = 9$ we get:
$$
\dim(M_{3 \times 3}(\Bbb R)) = \dim(S) + \dim(A)
$$ Hence:
$$
S \cap A =  \left\{ 0 \right\}\\
S \oplus A = M_{3 \times 3}(\Bbb R)
$$

Is my approach to the answer correct? Do I need to be more rigorous?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems good. I'd just be more careful with the word "assume" - you're actually proving these statements. I think this is more about grammar than math, but anyway (I'll understand english is not your first language, it's not mine either).

For example, you don't assume that $S$ and $A$ are subspaces of $M_3(\Bbb R)$, they actually *are* subspaces (even more fundamentally, they're subsets of $M_3(\Bbb R)$. You have proven that too. I'd have skipped that, being too lazy).

Also, you don't assume that $\dim S + \dim A = 9$. This is true, and you have shown us a proof.

Lastly, just to write less, I'd call $E_{ij}$ the matrix which has $1$ in position $(i,j)$ and zero everywhere else just to say that $B_s = \{E_{ij}+E_{ji} \mid 1  \leq i\leq j \leq 3\}$ and $B_a = \{ E_{ij}-E_{ji} \mid 1 \leq i < j \leq 3\}$.

Comment: Yeah, it's not my main language and I totally agree with u that I've used the word "assume" wrong sometimes during the post. But besides that... Is everything good. Should I be more rigorous or is that a nice way to proof things?? I'm new to this rigorous marh world haha

Comment: I think you were rigorous enough. Keep this up and you'll be fine. I think linear algebra is the best subject to start learning proofs.

Comment: I'm loving it.. I'm a physics student. How about u?

Comment: Cara. Você é br... Ime-Usp. Parabéns por estar no mestrado... estou na UFMG. Alguma recomendação  de livro para algebra linear?

Comment: Good that you're enjoying it! I just entered a master program in math. I think we shouldn't start chatting on the comments here, usually people frown upon it. You're very welcome to send me an email (it's in my webpage) or search me up on facebook, though. :-)

Comment: "Um Curso de Álgebra Linear", from Flávio Coelho and Mary Lilian Lourenço is good for a start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44895/discussion-between-bruno-reis-and-ivo-terek).

Answer (score 0):

So, you've proven that $\dim M_3(\Bbb R) = \dim S + \dim A$. But you should also show that $\dim(S \cap A) = 0$. You assert this at the bottom of your post, and it's pretty easy to show.

---

EDIT

Like you said above, $\dim(S + A) = \dim S + \dim A - \dim(S \cap A)$. So you have $\dim(S + A) = 9 - \dim(S \cap A)$. But unless $\dim(S \cap A) = 0$, you haven't shown what you need to.

Nothing forces $S \cap A = \{ 0 \}$, and so this condition must actually be checked. For example, let $T$ be a $3$-dimensional subspace of $S$ (for example, the diagonal matrices). Since $S + T = S$, we certainly don't have $S + T = M_3(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Thanks my friend! But $S \cap A$ is proved because of the relation of dimensions... ty anyway!

Comment: Not necessarily; see my edit to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Any $n \times n$ matrix $B$ can be written uniquely as a sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew symmetric matrix: 
\begin{align*}
B = \frac{1}{2}(B+B^t) + \frac{1}{2}(B-B^t)
\end{align*} 
where $B^t$ denotes the transpose of $B$. Thus $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) = S + A$. If $B \in S \cap A$, then $B^t = B$ and $B^t = -B$ and hence $B$ is the zero matrix. It follows that $S \oplus A = M_{n \times n}(\Bbb R)$.

We haven't used dimension argument. However, it is not difficult to see that
\begin{align*}
\dim(S) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}, \qquad \dim(A) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a marginally different viewpoint (really an addendum to Ivo's answer
above):

When dealing with subspaces, it is usually fruitful to look for operators
such that the kernel or range yields those subspaces.

(Also, using the Frobenius norm for matric operators often simplifies calculations.)

Let $L(X) = {1 \over 2} (X-X^T)$, then it is easy to check that $S=\ker L$ and $A={\cal R}L$.

If we use the inner product $\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{tr} (A^T B)$
we can check that $L=L^T$ (in the sense that $\langle A, L(B) \rangle
= \langle L(A), B \rangle$) and so ${\cal R}L = {\cal R}L^T$ and hence
$M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb R) = \ker L \oplus (\ker L)^\bot = \ker L \oplus {\cal R}L^T = \ker L \oplus {\cal R}L$.

If we let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix of zeroes except for a $1$ at the $i,j$ position, then we can quickly check that the collection
$\{E_{ij} -E_{ji} \}_{i <j} \cup \{ E_{ij} + E_{ij} \}_{i \le j}$
is a basis for $M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb R) $.

Since $L(E_{ij} -E_{ji}) = E_{ij} -E_{ji}$ and
$L(E_{ij} + E_{ij}) = 0$, we see that $\{ E_{ij} + E_{ij} \}_{i \le j}$ is a basis for $S=\ker L$ and hence $\{E_{ij} -E_{ji} \}_{i <j} $ is a basis for
$A={\cal R}L$.

In particular, $L$ is the orthogonal projection onto $A$.

The operator $M(X) = {1 \over 2} (X+X^T)$ would work equally well, and
result in the orthogonal projection onto $S$ (note that $M=I-L$).